# spark - RDD process twice after persist

Tags: apache-spark

I made a RDD and created another RDD from origin like below.

```
val RDD2 = RDD1.map({
  println("RDD1")
  ....
}).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

RDD2.foreach({
  println("RDD2")
  ...
})
...so on..
```

I expected that RDD1's process does ONLY one time, because RDD1 is saved on memory or disk by persist method.

BUT somehow "RDD1" is printed after "RDD2" printed like below.

```
RDD1
RDD1
RDD1
RDD1
RDD2
RDD2
RDD2
RDD2
RDD2
RDD1 -- repeat RDD1 process. WHY? 
RDD1
RDD1
RDD1
RDD2
RDD2
RDD2
RDD2
RDD2
```

Comment: when first "RDD1" is printed all, I can guarantee that process with RDD1 is done. It does same work twice.

Comment: I guess you did some `collect` action at the end?
 https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#persist-- also returns an RDD.

Comment: @davidshen84 yes I did collectAsMap() at the end of code

Comment: For both *RDD1* and *RDD2*? Remember two major concepts in Spark which are transforming and action. The transforming will not have any effect on the RDD until you take action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of spark. Like most of the operations persist in spark is also lazy operation.  So, even if you add the persist for the 1st RDD, spark doesn't cache the data unless you add any action after the persist operation. The map operation is not an action in spark and it is also lazy.

The way to enforce the caching is to add `count` action after the persist of `RDD2`

```
val RDD2 = RDD1.map({
   println("RDD1")
   ....
}).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

RDD2.count // Forces the caching
```

Now if you do any other operation the RDD2 won't be recomputed

Comment: is there any configuration option we may use to force caching? i.e. without calling action methods

Comment: No, this is by design of spark. You have to force caching by invoking action on the Rdd

Comment: from Spark RDD documentation webpage: "By default, each transformed RDD may be recomputed each time you run an action on it. However, you may also persist an RDD in memory using the persist (or cache) method, in which case Spark will keep the elements around on the cluster for much faster access the next time you query it"

Comment: it's a bit confusing, so the webpage says that persist makes RDD to be cached for the future use while you propose that it is a lazy operation

Comment: Well it persists in the cache but not immediately. It persists only after an action is called on this. For reference please see the book https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-caching.html. This explicitly mentions that the spark cache is lazy operation.

Comment: Spark cache operations are lazy. Here is the book which confirms the claimhttps://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-caching.html. You could also dive Deep on this by googling the spark cache lazy. The implementation of cache evaluates the dataframe only if an explicit action is called. Not any other lazy operation

Comment: I see. what's the point of using "persist" then, if it does not persist in the cache immediately. we may simply use any action function instead. "persist" seems quite useless for me now

Comment: I am not sure why the design decision was like that. You could drop a mail to spark apache regarding this.